# 503 Error when switching node.js deployment from server.js to index.js (beginner)

Tags: javascript, node.js

For reference, I'm using *The Node Beginner Book*'s tutorials, which is where the code comes from.

Edit: Based on a suggestion, I went in through ssh and manually started my index.js, and the server was working ('Hello World' instead of 503)! However, as soon as I exited the shell, the server went down again and I'm getting 503s.

/edit

I am able to get a simple server running by modifying my server.js file. I was using the following example code:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

However, when I move to the next lesson, which introduces an 'index.js' file in addition to the server.js file, I get a `503` on my site.

Below is the updated server.js:

```
var http = require("http");

function start() {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    console.log("Request received.");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
  }

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080);
  console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

And the index.js:

```
var server = require("./server");

server.start();
```

The error I'm getting from the server's error log is:

```
[Sun Jun 01 02:26:16.925881 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 32501:tid 3071784068864] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sun Jun 01 02:26:16.925962 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 32501:tid 3071784068864] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1) for 60s
[Sun Jun 01 02:26:16.925977 2014] [proxy_http:error] [pid 32501:tid 3071784068864] [client 2601:9:80:13a6:2514:b96:165:4791:55892] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

I have no clue what any of this means, so any help would be appreciated. I feel like the only thing that changed is I'm requiring the index.js file to be called first--and I don't know if the server *knows* to do that, but I also don't know how to check.

Edit: Changed the code to port 3000 based on comment. Still getting what seems to be same error:

```
[Sun Jun 01 03:12:14.720412 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 32716:tid 3071716927232] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sun Jun 01 03:12:14.720475 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 32716:tid 3071716927232] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1) for 60s
[Sun Jun 01 03:12:14.720484 2014] [proxy_http:error] [pid 32716:tid 3071716927232] [client 2601:9:80:13a6:2514:b96:165:4791:1226] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Sun Jun 01 03:12:14.923474 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 32716:tid 3071708534528] AH00940: HTTP: disabled connection for (127.0.0.1)
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the port number from `8080` to something else, like `3000`, just to see what's happening? Maybe you have another thing listening on that port. I've replicated this code on my machine and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros I changed the port to 3000 and did a redeploy. Strangely, I'm still getting the same error! I've tried a few times, so I'm fairly certain the new deploy 'took.' (New error codes pasted into the bottom of the OP for reference.)

Comment: Do you see the console message "Server has started" ?

Comment: Ok, but on the new log, as far I can see, you're still trying to make a request on port `8080`. Maybe you should try `localhost:3000` instead of `localhost:8080` on your browser.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros I'm doing this all remotely--I'm not sure of my server setup exactly (I'm new to this, and using gandi.net's simple hosting), but I think it's only listening on 8080. It works fine on localhost. Should have pointed that out, sorry!

Comment: Well, if you're not even seeing the "Server has started." message on your console, it didn't even started. Maybe you have another instance of node.js running somewhere else. If you are on a Unix based machine, you can run a `killall node`, before trying again. If you're on Windows, try `taskkill /IM node.exe`

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros That was promising. I went in through ssh and tried to killall node, but there wasn't one running. So I went in and manually started my index.js (which I though that deploying through git would do...), and the server was working! However, as soon as I exited the shell, the server went down again and I'm getting 503s. (Adding this info back into OP too...)

Comment: You ran `killall node` and no node.js process running: Ok.
You ran `node index.js` and the server has started (You saw the message "Server has started."): Ok.
You exited the shell: Not ok. If you exit the shell, the node.js process running there is dead. So, you'll not be able to make a request to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54859/discussion-between-rodrigo-medeiros-and-roccomaxamas).

Answer (score 0):

You created server using server.js which worked and showed "Hello World", meaning that you ran server.js file.
After adding index.js, are you still executing server.js? i assume this is not what you are doing because its quite obvious that you would run index.js now and not server.js.

Because i am running your code as it is with port 8080 and its working.